# Loop through html list and get the content

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am dealing with a page that have the following structure.

```html
<section id='famous'>

<li class="list-entry" id="samething">
   <span class="list-item item-type">
      <a href="link-1">Movies</a>
   </span>

   <span class="list-item item-name item-title">
      <a href="link-2"> Title 1</a>
   </span>

   <span class="list-item item-uploaded"> 
      <a href="link-2"> Title 1</a>
   </span>
</li>


<li class="list-entry" id="samething">
   <span class="list-item item-type">
      <a href="link-1">Movies</a>
   </span>

   <span class="list-item item-name item-title">
      <a href="link-2"> Title 1</a>
   </span>

   <span class="list-item item-uploaded"> 
      <a href="link-2"> Title 1</a>
   </span>
</li>



<li class="list-entry" id="samething">
   <span class="list-item item-type">
      <a href="link-1">Movies</a>
   </span>

   <span class="list-item item-name item-title">
      <a href="link-2"> Title 1</a>
   </span>

   <span class="list-item item-uploaded"> 
      <a href="link-2"> Title 1</a>
   </span>
</li>

</section>
```

Here is my code up until now.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const main = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goto('link-to-my-website')

  await page.waitForSelector("section[id='famous']");

  // const movies = await page.$$('#famous > li.list-entry');
  // for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  //   const element = movies[i];
  //   console.log(element);    
  // }

  const movies =  await page.$$('#famous > li.list-entry', el => el.innerText);
  movies.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
  });

  await browser.close()
}

main()
```

Now I can't figure out how to get the contents of the `span` into an array. So that I can access the link in the `a` tag. Please help!!

Thanks

Comment: What is the console output at the moment ?

Comment: @nubinub list of objects

Comment: And what do you want exactly in your array? The movies titles? The movies links?

Comment: yes, the movie titles, and links in array of arrays

Comment: one array for each `li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [puppeteer documentation](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pageselector-1), `page.$$` returns an array of `ElementHandle`. Those elements offers some [selection methods](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#elementhandleselector) and  [evaluation methods](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) as well. You should be able to query the sub elements you want. For instance:

```
const movies =  await page.$$('#famous > li.list-entry');
for (const movie of movies) {
    const name = await movie.$eval('.item-name > a', el => el.innerText);
    const itemUploaded = await movie.$eval('.item-uploaded > a', el => el.innerText);
    console.log(name, itemUploaded);
}
```

Comment: you know `link2` is not a class name? Does `.link2` work correctly?

Comment: That didn't completely solve my problem but it helped me move a bit forward, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do this with 1 css-selector?

```js
const $$ = (selector, cb) => new Promise( resolve => 
  resolve([...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].map(cb) ) );

$$("#famous li.list-entry span a", el => el.innerText).then(r => console.log(r));

// or even simpler
$$("#famous a", el => el.innerText).then(r => console.log(r));
```

```html
<section id='famous'>
  <ul>
    <li class="list-entry" id="samething">
      <span class="list-item item-type">
      <a href="link-1">Movies</a>
   </span>

      <span class="list-item item-name item-title">
      <a href="link-2"> Title 1</a>
   </span>

      <span class="list-item item-uploaded"> 
      <a href="link-2"> Title 2</a>
   </span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-entry" id="samething">
      <span class="list-item item-type">
      <a href="link-1">Movies</a>
   </span>

      <span class="list-item item-name item-title">
      <a href="link-2"> Title 1</a>
   </span>

      <span class="list-item item-uploaded"> 
      <a href="link-2"> Title 2</a>
   </span>
    </li>

    <li class="list-entry" id="samething">
      <span class="list-item item-type">
      <a href="link-1">Movies</a>
   </span>

      <span class="list-item item-name item-title">
      <a href="link-2"> Title 2</a>
   </span>

      <span class="list-item item-uploaded"> 
      <a href="link-2"> Title 1</a>
   </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: I tend to believe that OP does want to provide an array of the same size as the `li` count, which is impossible with this one selector.

Comment: @nubinub do you want me to change the html to the one I'm working with

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe a reducer would help (from the result of `$$("#famous li")`)

Comment: Thanks @KooiInc , I'll try it later. Thanks v much